# How to get vs goto closing html tags instead of closing '>' using Visual Studio/Express key-bindings?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How to get vs goto closing html tags instead of closing '>' using Visual Studio/Express key-bindings?

Using the key-binding in Visual Studio/Express 2010 (Ctrl-[, or Ctrl-]) will take you to the matching close/open syntax marker.  If on closing `}` it will take you to the opening `{` is on `#endregion` it takes you to the matching `#region` etc.

But, when in HTML it takes one from the opening `<` to the `>` of the tag, but not to the `</` tag -- which is often where I'd like to go.  Is there a way to add/change this behavior in Express or Pro?

Answer (score 0):

If the caret is over the < or > then you alternate between these. If the caret is over the name of the tag then you will jump between opening and closing tags.

Comment: Nope -- I thought that too, but no.

Comment: You are right. I made the mistake to test this with XML file instead of HTML thinking it will behave the same.